# implementing input tag functionality to an icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a date picker feature when i click on the input part the date picker appears but when i click on the icon displayed next to it i don't get anything and i want to apply same functionality so that i can open it with icon or input box.

I tried converting the icon area into an input but i loose my icon

```
 <input id="TimeReleased" name="TimeReleased" class="input-small"
     placeholder="Release Date" data-val="true"  type="text" value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" 
     data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" required/>
  <span class="add-on">
        i class="icon-calendar" data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" data-val="true"></i>
  </span>
```

Comment: Incorrect code at "i class"
<span class="add-on">
        i class="icon-calendar" data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" data-val="true"></i>
  </span>

Comment: Which library do you use for the date picker?

Comment: There's probably some `open()` function that you can call, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery UI Datepicker then how about putting your icon inside a label element? It probably also works for other datepickers.

```
<label>Date</label>
<div class="input-append">
    <input id="TimeReleased" name="TimeReleased" class="input-small" 
          placeholder="Release Date" data-val="true" 
          type="text" value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" 
          data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" required/>
    <label for="TimeReleased" class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></label>
</div>
```

[Example stole here :)](http://jasenhk.wordpress.com/2013/03/09/jquery-datepicker-with-bootstrap-icon/)